# Error on Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage

When I try this delete function in angular and Firebase

```
/item.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseService } from '../../services/firebase.service';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.css']
})

export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  id:any;       

  constructor(
    private firebaseService: FirebaseService,
    private router: Router      
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onDeleteClick(){
    this.firebaseService.deleteItem(this.id);

    this.router.navigate(['Items']);
   }
 }
```

on the firebase service

```
/firebase.service.ts

deleteItem(id){
 return this.items.remove(id);
}
```

the console return this error

```
Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `child` at index 0: Expected string
```

The record is deleted from the Firebase but it always shows me that error. 
Any ideas?

Thank

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including the Service.

Comment: Not being familiar with firebase, but I would guess that `this.id` is a number in `this.firebaseService.deleteItem(this.id)` and firebase expects a string in `return this.items.remove(id)`. Or at least some type of mismatch of type somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Firebase API:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#child

So the `child` method can only get a `String` which is a:

> Relative path from this location to the desired child location.

And it returns a reference to the child's location at the Firebase storage. The console error you received means that the argument passed to `child` wasn't a `String`.

In your case, if `id` is a number like Alex pointed out in the comments, it could cause that error.